# How to capture a numeric value from a URL in Django 3?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Am I using (\d+) correctly??

when I'm using it, I get error Page not found!
when I'm not using it, I get (Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.)

**app/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^reporters/(?P<report_id>\d+)$', views.report, name="entries"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def report(request, report_id):
"""show a reporter's all reports"""
reporter_n = Reporter.objects.get(id=report_id)
entries = reporter_n.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
context = {'reporter_n': reporter_n, 'entries': entries}

return render(request, "newsblog/reports.html", context)
```

Comment: Can you share your view?

Comment: I edited the question now you can see views.py!

Comment: Probably the error is where you are calling the url. Maybe in you template you are not passing correctly the report_id when you form the url. Sorry for the vague answer, I can't comment yet.